# PHP PDO fetchAll fails with latin characters

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2005, pdo, encoding

I faced a problem with reading the resaults of a `select query` which it brings back some strings that contains latin character. In my case i´m using the PDO function with ODBC driver on Windows to connect to a SQL server 2005, the table char set as i saw in sql server is "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and when i `print_r` the resault the array contains � characters this is the php code:

```
        try {
        $pdo = new PDO ("odbc:SQL_FLOC", $username, $password);
        //$pdo->exec("SET CHARACTER SET ISO8859-1");
        $sql=$pdo->prepare('select * from meteo.dbo.Causa');
        $sql->execute();
        $resultado=$sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        //Lo convertimos en formato json
        //$resultado = iconv('UCS-2LE', 'UTF-8', $resultado);
        print_r ($resultado);
        }
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo($e->getMessage());
        exit;}
```

I already tried CHARSET and it didn't

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set default charset in .htaccess?

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Comment: it is on Windows and doesn't have .htaccess